ASP.NET Core MVC : hostpolicy.dll required
As you all remember, after encountering  many errors, I wrote the procedure to create ASP.NET Core MVC web sites, in the database-first flow, here:
Create an ASP.NET Core MVC application with database-first approach
(once on the page, please search for "This is the procedure").
I applied that at least twenty times with no problem, but this time, when  doing  exactly the same, I meet a compilation error, and I should like someone to find an explanation, why my procedure was quite OK the first twenty times, but not this time.
Here is the history of this project (first version of my question).
Do not forget that it is an ASP.NET Core MVC site, so I expected it to be published as such, rather than giving me news of a DLL of which I completely ignored it existed.
I created an ASP.NET Core 8.0 MVC project. There was no problem to add NuGet packages Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, plus the three others with names that begin the same and end respectively with Design, SqlServer, Tools.
No problem to get the connection string from the Server Explorer.
Scaffold-DbContext and the connection string, OK.
In the Models folder of the solution explorer, I fail to add an EF Core database-first wizard: hostpolicy.dll required.
I saw here that the problem already appeared with .NET 2.
It was already noticed that "the error message is unhelpful", and it was needed to add an option in appname.runtimeconfig.[dev.]json, but I see no file of this name in my project, do you think the solution can be adapted, or do you see another?
Even when adding ".NET 8" at the beginning of the search query, I obtain the same answer first.
Here is the full error message:

Table list error: a fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in
'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\efreveng7.2.6.287'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app.
The application was run as a self-contained app because 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\efreveng7.2.6.287\efreveng70.runtimeconfig.json' was not found
If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\efreveng7.2.6.287\efreveng70.runtimeconfig.json' file and specify the appropriate framework


Hi @user3500176, 1. verify that the .NET 8.0 SDK is correctly installed on your machine. 2.Ensure that the global tools for Entity Framework Core are updated to match the .NET version you're using. 3.Verify that you have the correct packages installed in your project.

Hello, thank you for your answer. First of all, it appears I am the only one to meet the problem, this was the first point to elucidate, and it seemed to me that the main way to know it was to ask the question. So: 1. I uninstalled the .Net 8 SDK from the Visual Studio 2022 Community installer, restarted Windows, and installed the .Net 8 runtime from VSinstall. Uh, did I miss anything ? Or shall I have to install the .Net SDK from (there)[https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/8.0]? - 2. I read (there)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet]

So, I saw that I shall have to type ´´dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef´´ in the NuGet console, in order to be sure. 3. Maybe you saw the first point in my procedure, install the four packages from "Manage the NuGet packages for the solution" and then verify the list in the "Installed" tab.

I did not have any doubt that I had to type two ticks (´) before and after a code in the forum (and I tried the two possible orientations), I shall read that again but the delay to modify my message will be over.

Sorry, after I read about the code quotation syntax we shall be tomorrow, and it can have an interest to know how things evolve now. I uninstalled EF 8.0.7, and when trying to install it again I am invited to give a version number because of the existence of a pre-version. I typed ´´´dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef -version 8.0.7´´´ but version is not recognised, so tomorrow night I shall have to try it at another place in the command line.

So, .Net 8 runtime is installed from the Visual Studio installer, and .Net 8 SDK from there : https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/d1adccfa-62de-4306-9410-178eafb4eeeb/48e3746867707de33ef01036f6afc2c6/dotnet-sdk-8.0.303-win-x64.exe
I should have said the uninstallation of the SDK was refused from the list of application in Windows because installed from Visual Studio, maybe an error from me ...

Until now, in Tools / NuGet package manager, I had three commands: Package manager console, Manage the NuGet packages for the solution, Package manager parameters. They are still there, except the second one is greyed out as inactive. This is for a solution I created just before asking the question.

Tonight, I shall have a more in-depth look at the version of Entity Framework installed, and comparison to the .Net version targeted by the solution.

So, I had to reinstall the workload for .Net development, then, adding MVC in the Program file appears more simple as I do not need any more to precise that I use SQL Server.

On the other end, I get a controller, but with no views. Did I look improperly, is there a way to generate a controller with its views ? I tried a right click in the code to add a view, and a message protested that this is not provided.

In the Visual Studio installation program, individual components, I searched "Entity Framework" : "Entity Framework 6 Tools" is installed. / Then I searched MVC : "ASP.NET MVC 4" is installed.

I said I installed the workload for .Net development, as you guess it is the one for web development.

You cannot create the view with controller unless you scaffold MVC Controller with views, using entity framework.

Until now I had it in the contextual menu. How do I scaffold it back ?

So, some days ago I reinstalled .Net 8 SDK. I now just re-uninstalled MVC4 in the individual components of Visual Studio 2022, and then reinstalled it. I then did the same for "Entity Framework 6 Tools".
I still have two types of MVC controllers proposed in "Add, new element", in the contextual menu of the Controllers folder in the solutions explorer (I translate from French):

MVC controller with read/write actions
MVC controller, empty.

I search for the third choice, that I had before reinstalling everything:

MVC controller with views, using Entity Framework


Any idea how I should reinstall that?
Should I reinstall in a different order?

Oh well, such a long story ...
I restored a backup, but it seems it was made just a little too late, I still had the error message that motivated the creation of this thread.
I installed .Net 8, saw that the version number was the same for the one installed on Windows as for the one installed in Visual Studio.
I remember I then had to repair the one on Windows.
When wanting to create a new element in the Controller folder, I still only had two types of controller proposed, not the one with Entity Framework.
I create a controller with read/write actions. It is not the one I want, so I create a HomeController, that is named automatically HomeController1 to avoid doubloons.
From that controller, I right click in an action (Index, for instance), and I ask to add a view. There, I see a dialog box with a tree-view on the left. Under MVC, the Razor views are proposed in the View node.
Just under the View node, I have a Controller node. In this Controller node, on the right of the dialog box I see the three controllers types I expected, including MVC Controller with Views, using Entity Framework.
With that, I obtain the dialog box to select the classes for the controller, and when I validate I obtain the default views I expected.
Perhaps you will admit that this is somewhat strange.
As I obtained the final result I wanted I can mark the thread as solved.
Considering the strange scenario, if somebody is interested I can provide screen copies in French.
And of course if someone knows how I can go back to the normal scenario I am interested.

I had a doubt, so I launched a CHKDSK. It seems it found nothing.

When you see the screen copies you will notice that some screens could benefit of a new version, concerning font sizes and sometimes size of dialog box.

Oh well ... The code of the page seems nice, but in the browser the page is white.
I tell you tomorrow what happens.

Today's update of Visual Studio seems to solve a lot of problems, which sounds as good news. Unfortunately, the connection to the data fails with a transient failure, whereas program.cs contains ``builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddSqlServer(cnxString, options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure());
var app = builder.Build();
``
and I execute that with admin rights.

Do you think I should open a new thread, as this one is marked as solved?

Got it. I was invited to install Docker, I do not exactly realise in which extent it helped.
Then I paid attention on installing version 8.0.8 of each of the basic packages.
Then it worked with that in Program.cs:
var connString = "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=True;Trust Server Certificate=True";
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddMvcCore();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<NorthwindContext, NorthwindContext>(options =>
     options.UseSqlServer(connString));


As you guess, this is to be done before creating the controller.
